# How to set total no. of days on x-aixs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

Want to display total no. of days at the bottom, it displays 365 days after that starts from day 1, is there any way show total no. of days please! display 425 instead of 060 at the end.

[image]

Have checked other relevant answers but I couldn't get succeed, your help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

```
    data1 = pd.read_csv(path1,names=['time','1','2','3','4','Value','6','7',],
                                sep=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=False)
    ax = pd.rolling_mean(data1['Value'],100).plot()
    date_fmt = '%j'
    formatter = dates.DateFormatter(date_fmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Someone better at matplotlib may have a cleaner idea, but if you're willing to add a column or change the index, calculating the running number of days is relatively straighforward.  Assuming your data is already daily, this will work.

```
df['day'] = range(df.index[0].dayofyear, df.index[0].dayofyear + len(df))
```

If it's not even days, some logic like this should handle it.

```
import numpy as np
import calendar

df['day'] = ((df.index.dayofyear - df.index[0].dayofyear + 1) +
              (df.index.year - df.index[0].year) * 
              np.where(df.index.map(lambda x: calendar.isleap(x.year - 1)), 366, 365))
```

Comment: Thanks @chrisb,  I have a date/time column in a format '2014-02-03 16:01:46', has more than one year of data, all I want to show starting from day 1 to total no. of days on the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks @chrisb, Basically I have 5 different csv files with different dates and data on it and want plot all in one plot with no. of days, for example: 1- (2011,2012,2013,2014 + data)/ 2- (6 months + data)/ 3- (2013,2014 + data)/ 4- (1 year + data)/ and 5- (14 Months + data). I am finding difficulty to plot reason every csv file starts with different date, that's the reason I was trying to convert into no. of days, so that I can plot all in one go with starting day - 1, for example:- csv file 2 fall short as compared to csv file 1. How to proceed, any hint, help highly appreciated.